# Regular Expression catching uk phone number

Tags: regex

I trying to create a regular expression to catch the following conditions, but totally failing to get my head around it (Friday) and need a bit of help please?

Trying to capture UK phone numbers starting with area code or no area code, but excluding mobiles.

example: 01316691234 or 6691234 but not any number starting with 07

got this so far `^[0-9]1?(\d{6,11})` but struggling to exclude the 07 numbers.

Comment: mobstar, you may wish to consult the UK National Numbering plan, because you make many assumptions that could catch you out.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the supposition that UK area codes:

- start with 0 and are followed by 1 (usual) or 2 (London);
- run to 3-5 digits
- are followed by a phone number 6-7 digits long

Whilst this seems sound to me, I'm no telecoms anorak so you'll need to modify accordingly if any part of this supposition is wrong:

```
/^(0[12345689]\d{1,3} ?)?\d{6,7}$/
```

Either way, it's a bit of a can of worms. Postscodes and phone numbers don't lend themselves well to REGEX; the more tightly you refine it, the more at risk you are from new rules being added tomorrow - e.g. if they launched a new area code starting 03.

Comment: Looks like your expression will handle (01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 08, 09 followed by 1 to 3 more digits) optional; followed by a space, and at least 6 to 7 digits.  I think what is needed is `/^(0[12345689]\d{1,3})?\d{6,7}$/` - including anchors to start and end of string too

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative look ahead to prevent numbers starting with "07" matching:

```
^(?!07)([0-9]1)?(\d{6,11})
```